Set different input fields in form when dropdown option is selected
So I want to set different input fields dynamically in a form whenever an option in a dropdown is selected.
This is my form:
<form>
<p> Select an option: </p>
<select>
    <option>1</option>

    <option>2</option>

    <option>3</option>

    <option>4</option>
</select>
<input id="FirstOption"></input>
<input id="SecondOption"></input>
<input id="ThirdOption"></input>
<input id="FourthOption"></input>
</form>

e.g. if I select 1 it should add the first input field, if I select the second, it should remove the first and add the second one, viceversa - the reason of this is to add custom patterns for this to check validity.
I know it uses JavaScript, but I do not know how to select the different options inside the dropdown to do these functions, as well as hiding the inputs that do not correspond to the option.

If all you want to do is pass back the selected option of the drop down, give your select element a name property that matches the parameter name of your post method. Otherwise, if you want to manipulate the form to set a specific input value, look at addEventListener and the onchange event for the drop down. addEventListener

Firstly you should be using a group of type="radio" inputs for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

@JanKyuPeblik, why should this be radio instead of select?

@mykaf This behavior is exactly the purpose of a radio group. Using a select and a separate set of inputs is misapplication of those. HTML is not perfect, but you should start by choosing the most appropriate elements for the task. In this case, that is a group of radio inputs.

So then, @JanKyuPeblik, what is the exact purpose of a select if not for this? I agree that there is no need for select AND inputs.

Without the inputs there's less of a hard line. There's a reasonable answer or two over here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/456/when-should-i-use-a-select-box-instead-of-radio-buttons

If you want to achieve it only by javascript, then you can use an event listener on the options and then display input fields dynamically by hiding input fields with a css class that will hide them.


const optionSelect = document.getElementById('optionSelect');
const inputFields = {
    "1": document.getElementById('FirstOption'),
    "2": document.getElementById('SecondOption'),
    "3": document.getElementById('ThirdOption'),
    "4": document.getElementById('FourthOption')
};

optionSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const selectedValue = this.value;

    Object.values(inputFields).forEach(input => {
        input.classList.add('hidden');
    });

  
    if (selectedValue && inputFields[selectedValue]) {
        inputFields[selectedValue].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
});
.hidden {
         display: none;
        }
<form>
    <p>Select an option:</p>
    <select id="optionSelect">
        <option value="">--Select an option--</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input id="FirstOption" class="hidden" placeholder="First Option Input">
    <input id="SecondOption" class="hidden" placeholder="Second Option Input">
    <input id="ThirdOption" class="hidden" placeholder="Third Option Input">
    <input id="FourthOption" class="hidden" placeholder="Fourth Option Input">
</form>



